# Phoenix - Unknown column 'm0.field' in 'field list'`

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I run a simple test to my controller and then preload the association

```
  test "shows chosen resource", %{conn: conn, country: country} do
    mobile = Repo.insert! %Mobile{country_id: country.id}
    mobile = Repo.preload(mobile, :country)
    conn = get conn, mobile_path(conn, :show, mobile)
    assert json_response(conn, 200)["data"] == %{"id" => mobile.id,
      "country_code" => mobile.country_code,
      "number" => mobile.number}
  end
```

And then I received an error of ** (Mariaex.Error) (1054): Unknown column 'm0.country_code' in 'field list'

This is my controller.

```
`def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    mobile = Repo.get!(Mobile, id)
    render(conn, "show.json", mobile: mobile)
  end`
```

This is my model.

```
    schema "mobiles" do
    field :country_code, :string
    field :number, :string

    belongs_to :person, Person.Person
    belongs_to :country, Person.Country
    has_many :mobile_audits, Person.MobileAudit, on_delete: :delete_all

    timestamps() 
end
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:number, :person_id, :country_code])
    |> validate_required([:number])
    |> assoc_constraint(:country)
  end
```

This is my migration files.

```
defmodule Person.Repo.Migrations.CreateMobile do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:mobiles, primary_key: false) do
      add :id, :binary_id, primary_key: true
      add :country_code, :string
      add :number, :string
      add :person_id, references(:persons, type: :binary_id)

      timestamps()
    end
    create unique_index(:mobiles, [:number])

  end
end

defmodule Person.Repo.Migrations.CreateCountry do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:countries, primary_key: false) do
      add :id, :binary_id, primary_key: true
      add :code, :string
      add :name, :string
      add :iso_codes, :string

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```

What I am missing? I generated this project using `mix phoenix.new hello_phoenix --database mysql`

Comment: Did you conduct the migrations?

Comment: Yes. This is my `iex -S mix` session query. `iex(4)> Repo.all Mobile
[debug] QUERY OK source="mobiles" db=8.6ms
SELECT m0.`id`, m0.`country_code`, m0.`number`, m0.`person_id`, m0.`country_id`, m0.`inserted_at`, m0.`updated_at` FROM `mobiles` AS m0 []
[]`

Comment: What's `mariaex`? What DB engine are you using?

Comment: I edited my answer. I use mysql as my database.

Comment: Are you sure your test database is migrated correctly? You can do this to remigrate: `MIX_ENV=test mix do ecto.drop, ecto.create, ecto.migrate`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I spend hours on determining whats wrong in my model, controller, migrations and test files and this is the only solution, i'm new in phoenix.

Comment: @Dogbert, there should be an alias for that `mix ecto.reset` by default